# Button inside of div not working after clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Trying to build a dashboard that lets me test animations while linking and unlinking boxes. Got everything working, but when I add the link function, I found that the link doesn't work after the parent element has been cloned. I want it to work so that when someone clicks the left box, the right two boxes show whatever animation is selected as long as the link is active. If the link is inactive, the unlinked box does not animate. [Using animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) for the animations.

Here's the html:

```
<div id="animations-container">
    <center>
    <button name="slideInLeft" class="animation-selector selected">Slide In Left</button>
    <button name="slideInDown" class="animation-selector">Slide In Down</button>
    <button name="zoomInUp" class="animation-selector">Zoom In Up</button>
    <button name="zoomIn" class="animation-selector">Zoom In</button>
    <button name="pulse" class="animation-selector">Pulse</button>
    <button name="wobble" class="animation-selector">Wobble</button>
    <button name="shake" class="animation-selector">Shake</button>
    </center>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="graphs">
        <a href=# class="linked-button"><div class="block"><div class="content-block" style="height:280px; background-image:url(current-open-issues-by-opco.png);"></div></div></a>
        <div id="linked" class="linked block animated slideInLeft"><div class="content-block" style="height:237px; background-image:url(days-remaining-to-remediate-open-issues.png);"></div><div class="link-icon"></div></div>
        <div id="linked" class="linked block animated slideInLeft"><div class="content-block" style="height:350px; background-image:url(root-cause-of-ltm-issues.png);"></div></div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

and here's my jquery:

```
<script>
 $(function() {
    $(".linked-button").on('click', function() {
        $('.linked').remove().clone(true, true).appendTo('#graphs');
    });
});
$(function() {
    $(".animation-selector").on('click', function() {
        var animation = $(this).attr("name")
      // console.log("changeclass");
    $(".linked").removeClass().addClass('linked block animated');
    $(".linked").addClass(animation);
    $("#animations-container :button").removeClass('selected');
    $(this).toggleClass('selected')
  });
});
$(function() {
    $(".link-icon").on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('faded');
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('linked');
    });
});
```

Also replicated it in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3hjfj/

Update - working! Thanks - this was my first stackoverflow question - nice to get my cherry popped.  Here's the new code:

```
$(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.linked-button', function() {
        $('.linked').remove().clone(true, true).appendTo('#graphs');
    });
    $('body').on('hover', '.linked-button', function() {
        $('.link-icon').toggleClass("link-hover");
    });
    $('body').on('click', '.animation-selector', function() {
        var animation = $(this).attr("name")
          // console.log("changeclass");
        $(".linked").removeClass().addClass('linked block animated');
        $(".linked").addClass(animation);
        $("#animations-container :button").removeClass('selected');
        $(this).toggleClass('selected')
    });
    $('body').on('click', '.link-icon', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('faded');
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('linked');
        $('.transparent-blue').fade();
    });
    $('body').on('mouseenter', '.link-icon', function() {
        $('.transparent-blue').show();
    });
    $('body').on('mouseleave', '.link-icon', function() {
        $('.transparent-blue').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: the fiddle has a different code than the one provided here.

Comment: Chris, in the html above, you set same id "linked" for both divs, this can bring problems, try to leave the divs without id.

Comment: Thanks Ricardo - just learning that - didn't understand it until I started to realize how ids and classes are used in jquery

Answer (score 2):

Apart from not needing multiple document ready functions, the event handlers are applied only to the objects with those classes that exist at the time they are run, so the cloned objects do not get them. Try this instead:

```
$("document").on("click", ".link-icon", function() {

$("document").on("click", ".animation-selector, function() {
```

and

```
$("document").on("click", ".linked-button", function() {
```

Comment: For some reason this didn't work with the "document" - used body from comment below and it worked.  May just be me being stupid and not writing the code right - see updated question above for the working code.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for dynamically created elements:

```
$('body').on('click', '.animation-selector', function() {
    // do something
});
 $('body').on('click', '.link-icon', function() {
    // do something
});
```